# How can I get some data from another url in php?

Tags: php, html, sql

I am learning PHP so manythings I should know. Well, I use PHP to get data from another url : http://exampleurl.com . and in that url has a form :

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="/something"><div><textarea class="post" name="html" id="vB_Editor_001_textarea" rows="10" cols="60" style="width:650px; height:400px; " tabindex="1" dir="ltr">Some messages will be here</textarea></div>
</form>
```

I want to use PHP to get the value of textarea (all messages in that textarea), so can you tell me how to do that ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use file_get_contents and a function that getsbetween two strings

```
function getbetween($content,$start,$end)
{
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
return '';
}
```

then

```
$content = file_get_contents('URL HERE');
$start = '<textarea class="post" name="html" id="vB_Editor_001_textarea" rows="10" cols="60" style="width:650px; height:400px; " tabindex="1" dir="ltr">';
$end = '</textarea>';
$textarea = getbetween($content, $start, $end);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use file_get_contents($url);

E.g

```
$url = "http://exampleurl.com";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: You can then use AliTrixxs method below to extract the textarea

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch the values using this syntax

```
$name = $_POST['html'];
echo $name;
```

with echo you can print the content of $name var.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` for best parsing

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

For example:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://exampleurl.com');
$textarea = $html->find('textarea[id=test]'); 
echo $textarea->innertext; // Some messages will be here
```